# How change the theme of a timeseries plots in FusionCharts?

Tags: fusioncharts

I am not able to change the theme of a timeseries chart in a Python project. I have ensured that I cleared all cache, and that I have fusioncharts.theme.candy.js file is loaded in the .
 Now, I am doing this in my Python file after importing fusioncharts:

```
...
timeSeries.AddAttribute('chart', '{}') 
timeSeries.AddAttribute('caption', '{"text":"My Awesome Chart"}') timeSeries.AddAttribute('theme', '{"text":"candy"}') 
timeSeries.AddAttribute('yaxis', '[{"plot":{"value":"kW","connectnulldata":true},"format":{"suffix":"INR"},"title":"Book Sales"}]')
```

My challenge is : I am always getting the fusion theme, instead of candy. How can I change the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
 timeSeries.AddAttribute("chart", """{
                    **theme:"candy"**
                   }""")
```

Here is a demo in plain js - https://jsfiddle.net/bvypxemd/

​Please check the theme attribute is applied in the chart object of the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the chart in typescript then you can change the theme by simply change the theme that you want in chart generating function. Here is the code example..

```
const data = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Fusion Chart",
    "baseFont": "Verdana",
    "baseFontSize": "11",
    xaxisname: "Values",
    yaxisname: "Percentage(%)",
    theme: "candy", // here you need to change the theme
    use3DLighting: 0
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme by using

```
 chart: {
        theme: "fusion" //Apply theme (candy, umber)
      },
```

To know more about theme please [refer](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/introduction-to-themes-in-fusiontime)